# Is it possible to convert range to string?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to convert a range to a string? The idea is to make `alpha` = (`"abcdefg..."` etc). I want to do:

```
alpha.scan(/./) do |letters|
  puts "I have five vowels", if letters.include?("a", "e", "i", "o, "u")
end
```

Method 1:

```
alpha = ("a".."z").to_s # Still returns a range
```

Method 2:

```
alpha = *("a".."z").to_s # Same; returns a range
```

Comment: My _ugly_ code: `("a".."z").each_with_object("") { |c, s| s << c }` :)

Comment: `("a".."z").to_s` returns a string (`"a..z"`) and `*("a".."z").to_s` returns an array with this string as its only element

Comment: I don't think `scan` and `include` have anything to do with the actual question, i.e. creating a string `"abc...xyz"`. You should remove that part.

Comment: @Stefan yes but I need all letters to show as a string, not `a..z`

Comment: Im method 2 you wanted `[*'a'..'z']`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
("a".."z").to_a.join # => => "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

1. You need to convert range to array with `to_a`.
2. You can `join` the elements of the array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Your answer gave me a better way to write my code.